# Start subthread with arbitrary function including parameters

Tags: python, multithreading, parameter-passing

I would like to build a function, which checks if a subthread is already running and if not, start a subthread with any function and paramter given. As multithreading tool I use this post: [Is there any way to kill a Thread in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python)

The idea so far is the following:

```
from ThreadEx import ThreadEx

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__Thread = ThreadEx(name='MyClass',target="")
        self.GlobalVariable = "MyClass Variable"

    def SubThread(self, function): 
        if not self.__Thread.is_alive():
            print("Thread is not alive")
            self.__Thread = ThreadEx(target=function(),args=(self,))
            print("Thread is going to start")
            self.__Thread.start()
            print("Thread started")
        else:
            print("There is already a subthread running")

    def MyFunction1(self, argument1, argument2, argument3):
        self.SubThread(lambda: MyFunction1(self, argument1,argument2,argument3))

    def MyFunction2(self, argument1, argument2):
        self.SubThread(lambda: MyFunction2,argument1,argument2)


def MyFunction1(self, argument1, argument2, argument3):
    print(self.GlobalVariable)
    print("MyFunction1")
    print("Argument1: " + str(argument1))
    print("Argument2: " + str(argument2))
    print("Argument3: " + str(argument3))

def MyFunction2(argument1, argument2):
    print("MyFunction2")
    print("Argument1: " + str(argument1))
    print("Argument2: " + str(argument2))
```

unfortunately if I execute:

```
from Myclass import MyClass

self.MyClass = MyClass()
self.MyClass.MyFunction1("Test1","Test2","Test3")
```

The output is:

```
Thread is not alive
MyClass Variable
MyFunction1
Argument1: Test1
Argument2: Test2
Argument3: Test3
Thread is going to start
Thread started
```

So the function is executed before the thread starts. So my question is, how do I send MyFunction including all arguments to a subthread and being able to repeat this with any other function without write a routine each time. 
I was already looking for *args and **kwargs but I couldn't find the right syntax or it was the wrong way.

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
self.__Thread = ThreadEx(target=function(),args=(self,))
```

Notice the parentheses behind function. It means not the function is assigned to target, but the result of *calling* said function. So, the function is executed, it does its printing etc., *then* its output (`None`) is assigned to `target`, and then the thread starts.

Do this instead:

```
self.__Thread = ThreadEx(target=function,args=(self,))
```

---

The more generic alternative to those lambdas is to use `*args` and `**kwargs`, as you mention. It should look like this:

```
class MyClass:
   # ... other class code goes here
   def SubThread(self, function, *args, **kwargs):  # changed
     if not self.__Thread.is_alive():
       print("Thread is not alive")
       self.__Thread = ThreadEx(target=function,args=args, kwargs=kwargs)  # changed
       print("Thread is going to start")
       self.__Thread.start()
       print("Thread started")
     else:
       print("There is already a subthread running")

  def MyFunction1(self, argument1, argument2, argument3):
    self.SubThread(MyFunction1, self, argument1, argument2, argument3)  # changed, note explicit inclusion of self

# ... function code goes here

my_instance = MyClass()
my_instance.MyFunction1("Test1","Test2","Test3")
my_instance.SubThread(MyFunction1, my_instance, "Test1", "Test2", "Test3")  # note explicit inclusion of my_instance
```

Comment: Changing to 
self.__Thread = ThreadEx(target=function,args=(self,))
did not work out, but the generic alternative solves the problem very well! Thanks!